# How LZMA decompression algorithm works?

Tags: c, embedded, lzma

I am stuck of understanding how lzma decompress algorithm works, more precisely this function

```
int res = LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(CLzmaDec *p, Byte *dest, SizeT *destLen, 
        const Byte *src, SizeT *srcLen, ELzmaFinishMode finishMode);
```

which is in an infinite loop, with a fixed size for SizeT *destLen and SizeT *srcLen which have equal size, logically the destLen(uncompressed data) should be greater than srcLen(compressed data) with a predefined ratio, I didn't get how it works with an equal size or it could accept any size then it had a temp buff that will store data then and treat them with it's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is difficult to use indeed. It is built for incremental decompression. Thus the envisioned use case is like so:

- A program reads compressed data from a source like a file. The data is read in chunks, e.g. 1000 bytes at a time.
- Each chunk is decompressed into a buffer. The buffer is usually bigger, e.g. 2000 bytes. After decompressing a chunk, the destination buffer will be partially filled with data, e.g. 1738 bytes.
- For each chunk, the decompressed data will be further processed, e.g. written to a file.

So simplified code for decompressing a file and writing the result to another file looks like so:

```
file_in = open_file(...);
file_out = open_file(...);
while (!eof(file_in)) {
   len_in = read(file_in, buf_in, 1000);
   len_out = decompress(buf_in,len_in, buf_out, 2000);
   write(file_out, buf_out, len_out);
}
close(file_in);
close(file_out);
```

So the relevant parameters of `LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf` are:

- `dest`: pointer to destination buffer
- `destLen`: pointer to destination length. The caller sets the length to the allocated buffer size. `LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf` updates the length to contain the length of the decompressed data.
- `src`: pointer to source buffer
- `srcLen`: pointer to source length. The caller sets the length to the length of the compressed data in the buffer.  `LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf` updates the length to contain the number of processed bytes.

`srLen` can be tricky. In most cases, all data passed to the function will be processed. But in case the decompressed data does not fit into the destination buffer, it will only process part of the data. So the decompressed data needs to be written to the file to free up the destination buffer and the function needs to be called again with the remaining data. This has been omitted from the simplified code.

An additional omission is the finalization. At the end of the input file, `LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf` might need to be called one last time with a different finish mode.

Comment: Thanks @Codo for the great explanation just one more question, does LZMA allows streaming decryption ?

Comment: Do you mean "encryption/decryption" as in "with secret key" / "communication security"? Or do you mean "compression" / "decompression"? And I'm not sure what you mean with "streaming". Can you be more specific?

Comment: I meant compression/decompression context, decompressing with streaming means i can decompress in loop bloc by bloc i.e decompress(bloc2) doesn't depend on decompress(bloc1)' result, it's the case when using RLE but am not sure with LZMA

Comment: I'm still not sure what your mean: In my answer, a loop and chunk (similar to your "blocs"?) are used. But the compression of a chunk depends on the previous chunk. Just think of it as the state of the decompression engine. It is saved in the `CLzmaDec` structure and needs to be passed to each call. Compressing each block individually is possible as well but the decompression rate will be considerably lower. But then I don't understand why you mention a loop.

Comment: forget about the loop @Codo, am so grateful. just one more ambiguity, can I control the destLen in each iteration (i.e iteration 1: I need a buffer of 32 bytes, iteration 2 128 bytes….) if yes is there any rules in this case to set the srcLen size? Also it’s mentioned that LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf updates the length to contain the length of the decompressed data it means the parameter destLen define the max size of dest buffer but LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf can updates it to a value less than destLen, am I right ?

Comment: Your understanding of how `destLen` works is correct. You can use a different length on each call, it's the maximum size on function entry and the effective and likely smaller size on exit. But it is not possible to predict a matching `srcLen` as it depends on the data. If the original data consisted of all 0s, 10 bytes might decompress into 1000 bytes. And if the original data was completely random, the source and destination length are likely almost the same.

Comment: great, so a misuse of destLen and srcLen could it lead to wrong decompression result or to a loss and a damaged uncompressed data ? or LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf maintain a high level of protection when such case occurs.

Comment: What would a misuse of `destLen` and `srcLen` be?

Comment: for example setting destLen to very low value example 32 contrary to srcLen with a bigger value (ex: 128) could it occurs a loss of data or LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf will deny accepting new data until it finishs compression into destLen buffer.

Comment: LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf handles this reliably. After the call, you need to check if all source data has been processed (inidcated by the updated `srcLen`). If not, you have to call it again for the rest of the source data.

Comment: So @Codo LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf is built for incremental decompression, so can we stop for example in iteration n and we save the context of LZMA then we reset the soft then we try to start the decompression from iteration n+1, I want to know if it can be workable or not

Comment: All the context is stored in the `CLzmaDec` struct (plus memory referenced from there). If you could save and restore it, the proposed approach would work. However, there are no such functions and insufficient information about how to save and restore members like `probs`, `dic` and `buf`.